# Getting number of occurrence of record

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `user_stats_clicks` Where there is a column for `username` and `dsub`. What I did first is get the last records for the past 10 days from yesterday.

```
  SELECT * FROM  `user_stats_clicks` 
    WHERE  (`dsub` < CURRENT_DATE( )
    AND  `dsub` >= CURRENT_DATE( ) - INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

Now I want to count how much instance is there per `username`

I triend using this

```
SELECT * FROM  `user_stats_clicks` 
   WHERE  (`dsub` < CURRENT_DATE( )
   AND  `dsub` >= CURRENT_DATE( ) - INTERVAL 10 DAY)
GROUP BY `username`
```

However I'm stuck after that. How Can I count the occurrence for each username?

Comment: SELECT username, COUNT(*) FROM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding COUNT(*) to your SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
SELECT username ,COUNT(*) FROM user_stats_clicks WHERE ... GROUP BY  username
```